# Is there way to receive alerts on breaking news that's faster than typical RSS readers?

Tags: rss, feed, feed-reader, newsreader

All the RSS readers I've tried are slow, I need news within a minute or two of it being broken.

Sorry if this is posted in the wrong section.  Not sure where the appropriate forum is to ask.

Comment: Subscribe to [Bloomberg Professional](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/).

Comment: All RSS readers have configuration how frequent to poll sites

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking: yes.

RSS readers work the way that they query the URL they subscribed to in a given intervall for an XML file that is formatted in a defined way, pull it and display the contents.

What you could do to speed things is to shorten the interval: you could tell your reader to look for this file every minute.

Still when it comes to overall speed, you can find solutions that might fit better. My first thought for example is a node.js application (which is run on a server), that actively *pushes* news to a connected client, as soon as it is available. And I bet there are way more specialized solutions out there...!

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into node.js..the rss readers I've tried are a bit slow compared to a simple google search!

Comment: Node.js is NOT a feed reader but SERVER software! It is (put easy) JavaScript run on a server. This was just a technical example for technology, where the server pushes information (instead of the client pulling)!

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought this might be clear when I say it pushes to a *client*. However, I'll update the solution.